# playwright how to click on an element on a side bar

Tags: playwright

I'm learning "playwright" in js.

I can't do a simple thing: click on a link in a side menu.

The page is this:

[image]

the Dom is this one for the button :
[image]

and for the panel :
[image]

My test is:

```
await page.getByTestId('menu-toggle-icon').click();
await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Manage Taxes' }).click();
```

I get this error:

```
**Error: locator.click: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
```

Call log:

- waiting for getByRole('link', { name: 'Manage Taxes' })
- locator resolved to <a id="719e9b3e-b34d-5f8f-86df-0f011bbd206e" href="…>…
- attempting click action
- waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
- element is visible, enabled and stable
- scrolling into view if needed
- done scrolling
- element is outside of the viewport**

The last line "element is outside of the viewport" : what does it mean ? Is it the root cause of my problem ?

Comment: Maybe some animation after clicking the button. Have you tried adding a manual wait to see if this failure doesn't happen?

Comment: thanks @demouser123 : Yes I added manual wait. Without success, the same error appears.

Comment: Is the menu item visible on the screenshot made by Playwright after it failed?

Comment: @szogoon : no the menu is not visible on the screenshot. And that's the problem. It seems that playwright does not see it . And the menu is not visible on the "playwright runner" (lauched with --ui option)

Comment: Please share the site and complete, runnable code as a [mcve]. Without it, we can only guess the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the page is badly hydrated, so that button is rendered and enabled, but the listener is not attached when playwright is clicking. Check it like mentioned at https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#hydration

Comment: hi szogoo, thanks for your help. i tried what you mentionned, but without success. I tried also with some `page.waitForTimeout`, same : playwright do not see this menu. Nut I just saw this interesting topic : https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/21172